# Npx and npm arent working in the vscode terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio, next.js

I'm trying to create a react app in vscode and the npx create-react-app my-app
isnt working. Please what should i do?

I've watched a lot of videos and i can't find the solution
Vscode keeps saying npx : The term 'npx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have installed Node.js? You need this for `npm` and `npx`. `npx` comes packaged with `npm` (5.2.0 and higher), which itself comes with Node.js. If you haven't installed Node.js, you won't have access to `npx`. Download the installer from the [official Node.js website](https://nodejs.org/en)

After downloading, open a new terminal and run the following commands:

```
node -v
npm -v
npx -v
```

If you see version numbers, you know they have installed successfully. Then try running the command again.

If this still does not work, you may have an issue with your PATH environment variable. You may need to add them.

For Windows:

1. Search for "environment variables" in your system settings.
2. Click on "Edit the system environment variables."
3. In the System Properties window, click the "Environment Variables" button.
4. Under "System Variables", find the "Path" variable, and click "Edit..."
5. Add the path to where Node.js is installed, which usually is C:\Program Files\nodejs.

For Mac and Linux:

1. Open your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc file` (depending on your shell).
2. Add `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/node` at the end.
3. Run `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc`.